# Display Product GTIN in Woocommerce Email Order

Tags: php, woocommerce, plugins, product, email-notifications

I just installed this plugin [WooCommerce UPC, EAN, and ISBN](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-add-gtin/) and activate it to have the GTIN field on my single product page.

Everything is working fine, I have the field with the displayed value inside (example: product code: 123456 that is showed on product page).

What I want is when someone plac an order, when I get the order confirmation email on outlook there is an email template which shows me the product title, price, quantity, **BUT not showing the GTIN product code**.

How can I extract/display the GTIN to WooCommerce email template.

Comment: Note: This plugin is discontinued since 2 years.

Comment: That's true but there is a way to display the value on email template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way to get the GTIN code from the product, and to save it as custom order item, when the order is submitted, so it's displayed on orders and email notifications:

```php
// Utility function to get the GTIN code from the product object
function get_product_gtin_code( $product ) {
    return $product->get_meta('hwp_product_gtin');
}

// Utility function to get the GTIN label name
function get_gtin_label() {
    $label = get_option('hwp_gtin_text');
    return esc_html__( $label ? $label : 'GTIN');
}

// Save Product GTIN as custom order item and display it on orders (items) and emails
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'save_and_display_gtin_everywhere', 10, 4 );
function save_and_display_gtin_everywhere( $item, $item_key, $values, $order ) {
    if ( $gtin_code = get_product_gtin_code($values['data']) ) {
        $item->add_meta_data( 'gtin_code', $gtin_code );
    }
}

// Add readable "meta key" label name replacement
add_filter('woocommerce_order_item_display_meta_key', 'filter_wc_order_item_display_meta_key', 10, 3 );
function filter_wc_order_item_display_meta_key( $display_key, $meta, $item ) {
    if( $item->get_type() === 'line_item' && $meta->key === 'gtin_code' ) {
        $display_key = get_gtin_label();
    }
    return $display_key;
}

// Utility function to get the GTIN code from the order item object
function get_order_item_gtin_code( $item ) {
    return $item->get_meta('gtin_code');
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). It should work.

Comment: Thank you but where I need to put this code? in function.php?

Comment: Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin).

Comment: It works, but it's shown as an unordered list, and I would like it to be inline, example: Cod produs: 123123, thanks